# I wanted to snooze an alert using cloud scheduler. Is there any way to implement it in gcp?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I wanted to snooze an alert using cloud scheduler. But in cloud scheduler I have to provide an endpoint details. Is there any way to trigger/create a snooze for an alert via cloud scheduler?

I wanted to snooze an alert using cloud scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

You can pause a cron job, but you cannot "snooze" it for a set period of time via an API.

You can pause a scheduler cron job in the Console GUI or via the CLI:

```
gcloud scheduler jobs pause MY_JOB
```

To resume a cron job:

```
gcloud scheduler jobs resume MY_JOB
```

This document has more information:

[Create and configure cron jobs](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating#pause)